MWAA Installing Python Module
I am using Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow (MWAA) on AWS.
I have an instance running and I am able to load DAGS on.
I load the files to S3 and target the bucket and folder path to the DAGs, requirments.txt file and the plugins.
This is the requirements file:
pandas==2.2.3
boto3==1.35.31
sqlalchemy==1.4.54
mysqlclient==2.2.4
apache-airflow-providers-mysql[amazon]==5.7.1
apache-airflow[amazon]==2.10.2

I am able to make a connector to MYSQL confirming that airflow has installed the packages. I am now trying to run a DAG that contains pandas import pandas as pd. But it returns the error message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
This is the full error message:
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/ng_gtma/main.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/ng_gtma/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd                            # AWS
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I do not understand how the pandas module is not detected. The environment has targetted the correct file.
I tried to load the file and there is a module error too.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Hi, Is the MWAA in private or public network mode? Also could you add the dag example please.  I'm thinking your in private mode and have top level imports.
